# How pass variable in function setInterval with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, setinterval, anonymous-function

I want to pass a variable in a function inside `setInterval`, i'm tried with this code but doesn't work.

Anyway `function orologio(arg)` append in a div a variable returned by other function `orario_sisma` where the second argument (`formato_orologio`) is passed in function orologio.

With `click`event i must to stop the first setInterval and run it another time but with new argument.

How can i do this?

```
   var orologio_real= setInterval(orologio(1), 1000);



   $('#A').on('click', function(){
     clearInterval(orologio_real);  

     orologio_real= setInterval(orologio(0), 1000);
   });




 function orologio (formato_orologio){
    $('#remove').remove();
    var milliseconds= new Date();
        milliseconds= milliseconds.getTime();

    var real_time= orario_sisma(milliseconds, formato_orologio);
        real_time= '<div id="remove">'+real_time+'</div>';

    $(real_time).appendTo('#data-real-time');   
}
```

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this but it is a bad practice of coding

*code*

```
var orologio_real= setInterval(orologio, 1000,1);

   $('#A').on('click', function(){
     clearInterval(orologio_real);  

     orologio_real= setInterval(orologio, 1000, 0);
   });
```

Comment: Obvious duplicates don't need answers, just close votes (when you can).